# Finding a linear map $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ that satisfy conditions about the kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a linear map $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4$ that satisfy the following conditions (or explain why there can't be such linear map):
>
> 1. $\ker(T)=sp\{(1,-1,0)^T,(3,2,-5)^T  \} $
> 2. $\ker(T)=sp\{(1,-1,0)^T,(3,2,-5)^T  \},\operatorname{im}(T)=sp\{(2,1,1,-3)^T,(4,3,0,1)^T  \}$
> 3. $\operatorname{im}(T)=sp\{(2,1,1,-3)^T,(4,3,0,1)^T$

I don't know how to use the given information about the kernel and image to make a linear map so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does rank nullity theorem say?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik About 1. it doesn't really help since I have no info about the image. For 2. I guess it should equal $dim(\mathbb R^3)=3$ so I get $4\neq3$ which isn't right.

Comment: I said for second question only.... That is it... you have got it!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik OK so 2. was easy, thanks. Now how do I approach 1. ?

Comment: I could not type that in comment so i typed it as an answer.. i am sure there is a better way than what i have done but then I typed that for time being...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yeah I saw, anything helps. I edited a third part but I see that it's similar to 1.

Comment: Kin : That would not be better idea to leave it for me to do third part.. I have shown you first part please do the third part by your self and please feel free to ask if there is any issue... good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some Background**

Definitely knowing only the kernel of the map $T$ is incomplete information to find a map, unless the whole domain is the kernel i.e. $Ker \; T = \mathbb{R}^3$ in which case the map is the zero map. ($T \equiv 0$).

So in your questions there is no unique map but many if that exists. Because, if $Ker \; T$ is a proper subspace of the domain, then you can extend the basis of $Ker \; T$ to the basis of domain $\mathbb{R}^3$. (In all the above cases the $\mbox{ dim of } Ker \; T = 2$ which makes it a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose dim is 3, so we will get just one and only more vector while extending.)

After that take the vectors outside $Ker \; T$ to arbitrary vectors if $Im \; T$ is not specified.(In this case I can take the third basis vector outside $Ker \; T$ to arbitrary image in $R^4$.)

The image of $T$ if specified brings in a little more constraint, but then we also have the freedom to take the third basis vector to arbitrary vector in the given image space of $T$.

But then as you pointed out : Rank - Nullity theorem guarantees that we must have $ dim \; Ker \; T +  dim \; Im \; T = 3 $ so ANSWER TO Question 2 is impossible to find. (Another way of looking at it is because the new basis has only one vector outside $Ker \; T$, the image of $T$ is only span of this third basis vector's image as all the vectors are linear combination of basis vectors.)

Extension of vectors : Well you might be thinking how will I guess the third vector, as there are a bunch of vectors which can complete the basis by being the third basis vector. To overcome this problem note we have an inner product structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ here we have $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So if you apply Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization on the basis of $Ker \; T$ you will get two orthogonal vectors. Now in $R^3$ there is only one unique orthonormal vector to two given orthonormal vectors. (Prove it!)

Note that the only thing that connects the $Ker \; T$ and $Im \; T$ in different vector spaces, is the Rank - Nullity theorem. So the only thing that we can do best is check dimension compatibility.

Also a linear transformation is completely determined by its action on basis. So defining where $T$ takes its basis we actually spell out the map $T$. That's what we are going to do next.

---

**ANSWERS**

If you have understood the background finding the answers is routine now. By inspection $(1,0,0)$ is linearly independent to Kernel Bases given in 1,2 questions.(I don't use Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization as I readily obtain the the third vector from inspection.)

Because we are asked to find a map we will only find a map :

1) $T(1,0,0) = (1,0,0,0), \; T(v) = (0,0,0,0)$ if $v \not\in <(1,0,0)>$.

2) Is not possible as Rank Nullity Theorem is violated.

3) Choose the simplest basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ i.e. $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$, take define $T$ to be :

$T(1,0,0) = (0,0,0,0), T(0,1,0) = (2,1,1,-3), T(0,0,1) = (4,3,0,1)$.

@ GinKin : So I hope this answers all your questions completely.

@ Prafulla Koushik : I really liked Linear Algebra as a an undergraduate, and my favorite book is "Linear Algebra : A geometric viewpoint" whose author teaches you. So you must love the subject more ! :)

Comment: Thanks that was very detailed. Though I don't know Gram-Schmidt nor what is an orthonormal vector...

Comment: If you know inner product or dot product, its easy to explain both the things. Through example : let a and b be two vectors in R^3. They are orthogonal if $a \cdot b = 0$ (a is orthogonal to b), and if $a \cdot a = 1$ also $b\cdot b = 1$ (a and b are normal/unit vectors), then they are called orthonormal. Through Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization we produce orthonormal vector from arbitrary vectors. (Basically we remove projections of other basis vectors and then make it a unit vector.) Google it ! Its not very hard. :)

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{For First question}$

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\\k&l&m\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a-b\\d-e\\g-h\\k-l\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

what does this say about matrix if The resultant is zero?

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\\k&l&m\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\-5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}??\\??\\??\\??\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

what does this say about matrix if The resultant is zero?

Solve for first condition as that is easier than second....

$\textbf{For second question}$

What does rank nullity theorem say? (This is just for completeness)

Edit : Once you find values of $\{a,b,\cdots,l,m\}$ (If there exist) then you just have to consider

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\\k&l&m\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ This would give you first co ordinate in image of $T$

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\\k&l&m\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$This would give you second co ordinate in image of $T$

$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\\k&l&m\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$This would give you second co ordinate in image of $T$

Comment: It means that one of the vectors is linearly dependent right ? Why didn't you choose a $3\times 3$ matrix ? Also, how can I find the linear map from that ?

Comment: why would it be a $3\times 3$ matrix if the map is $T : \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$..

Comment: I thought that $kerT$ go from $\mathbb R^3$ to 0. Anyway, I don't see how does that let me find the linear map...

Comment: @GinKin look at the edit...

Answer (score 1):

A linear map is determined by its action on a basis. First of all, complete

$$\{v_1=(1,−1,0)^T,v_2(3,2,−5)^T\}$$

to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$; for example, $v_3=(1,0,0)^T$ is as good as infinitely many other vectors. Then fix any nonzero vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^4$ and define
$$
f(v_1)=0,\quad f(v_2)=0,\quad f(v_3)=w
$$
Why is $\ker f=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2)\}$?

What's the dimension of the image of $f$? (This is independent of $w$, as it can be easily seen.) So, what about question 2?

Question 3 is solved similarly, by assigning the image of vectors in a basis.

Answer (score 1):

If $ker(T) = sp\{ (1,1,0) \}$ then $ T(x,y,z) = (0,0,0,0)$ if and only if $x =y$ and $z = 0$. So let $T(x,y,z) = (x-y,z,0,0)$ then the kernel of $T$ is the set spanned by $(1,1,0)$.

If $Im(T) = sp\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0) \}$ then taking $G:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ such that $G(x,y,z) = (x,2y,z,0)$ would work.

This part is just to justify why it holds true for this $G$. Since for any $a$ and $b$ we have that $a(1,1,0,0) + b(0,1,1,0) = G(a,\frac {a+b} 2 , b )$ so $ sp \{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0) \} \subseteq Im(G) $ and you should be able to see that $Im(G) \subseteq sp\{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0) \}$.  Hence $G$ would satisfy $Im(G) = sp \{(1,1,0,0),(0,1,1,0) \}$

If you try to generalize this to your questions that might help.

Comment: How did you know to place $x,y,z$ like so $T(x,y,z) = (x-y,z,0,0) $?

Comment: Also, about the span is the subset of the image and the image is a subset of the span, we already know that they're equal so how does stating this helps ?

Comment: Since $T(x,y,z) = (0,0,0,0)$ if and only if $(x,y,z) = a(1,1,0)$ then $x = a = y $ and $z= 0$. This means that it will probably involve $x - y$ for one coordinate and $z$ by itself for another, and that $T$ was the first I could come up with. Little techniques like that will help a lot with these type of questions. Sorry abuse of notation, I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Also the rank nullity is useful. In my example $dim(ker(T)) = 1$ and $dim(\mathbb R^3) = 3$ so $dim(Im(T)) = 2$. The easiest way I could achieve this is by setting two coordinates to always be zero, So that the image of $T$ is a plane.